# Process intent when device is unlocked

Tags: android

I would like to start my activity when some broadcast is received:
1. if device is on - immediately (no problem here)
2. if device is off - when device comes on (and is unlocked)

Second point I don't know how to implement.
I was looking at PendingIntents and AlarmManager, but this doesn't account for device lock.
I would like to somehow "qeueu" intents and process them once device wakes AND is unlocked.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this system intents :

1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
2) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT

I am sorry but I didn't get your second problem.
Can you please provide more information?

Comment: I don't have problem registering receivers and processing events as they happen, what I would like is to "queue" received events and process them at a later time - when "user is present".

For example:
Device is sleeping/or locked. Broadcast receivers receive events and they "store/queue" them somewhere. But when device unlocks (user present or some similar receiver) I would like to start my main activity processing "stored/queued" events. Question is, how to store/qeueu events to process them at some later time?

Answer (score 0):

There's a broadcast called `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` but as far as I've read, it is *not* going to be fired reliably in the sense that you will always be informed when the user is present. I've seen this being fired on unlock. But then again, I can configure my device to not force me to unlock it.

Apart from that, sorry to say I haven't found anything in this direction; maybe it's enough for your purpose. You could also listen to changes of settings, phones being plugged in etc -- depending on your needs. Still, I feel there's something missing here in Android.

Comment: Putting aside how to detect if user is present, main question is how/where to "store/queue" events received when device is sleeping and locked, so that I can process them when device is unlocked.

Comment: @user1309702 I'd use a dedicated [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) file for that.